# NameError: name 'thisFunctionName' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror, traceback

I wrote a small python file to check the operation of some functions (functions.py) which has been successful - to a point. The code appears below:

```
import os
import datetime

def thisTime():
    now = datetime.now()
    return now

def thisDir():
    current = os.getcwd()
    return current
```

---

This code compiles and runs successfully. From the command console, I am evoking functions.py with the  following:

```
from functions import*
```

which allows me to do the following

```
>>> thisTime()
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 4, 20, 46, 1, 131363)
```

However when I issue `>>> thisDir()`, the following error appears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'thisDir' is not defined
```

---

Any help appreciated in understanding the nature of the error.

Comment: Are you sure you saved the file?

Comment: Check your spelling and indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Must be an indentation error.
Actually, thisTime() doesn't work:

```
>>> datetime.now()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'

>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 4, 12, 32, 38, 460157)
```

Try checking the spacing and tabbing using Notepad++'s Show All Characters, or something similar.
http://mattrefghi.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/ShowAllCharacters.png

Comment: 'thisTime() doesn't work' - that's interesting as it works for me. See my comment re environments

Answer (score 0):

Your call to datetime.now() was wrong. It's datetime.datetime.now() or you can import the datetime class individually like this:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

def thisTime():
    now = datetime.now()
    return now

def thisDir():
    current = os.getcwd()
    return current
```

The above code works. Here's sample:

```
~/Codes/py ⮀ python -i test.py
>>> thisTime()
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 4, 16, 53, 42, 969364)
>>> thisDir()
'/Users/masnun/Codes/py'
>>>
```

Assuming the source code is in functions.py, this code works perfectly fine for me:

```
from functions import *

print thisTime()
print thisDir()


 ~/Codes/py ⮀ python test.py
2014-01-04 17:00:04.254856
/Users/masnun/Codes/py
 ~/Codes/py ⮀
```

Comment: thanks I should have added, like you thisDir() worked for me using Python 2.7.6 in XP with the IDLE IDE.
Where it came unstuck, was using Python 3.3.3  in OSX 10.6.8 using the Pycharm IDE.